# Как импортировать модуль в Go

Tags: golang

Только начинаю изучать Go и столкнулся с такой проблемой: есть проект, который выглядит так

```
GoVersion
-go.mod
-client
--main.go
-network
--Network.go
--mod.go
-server
--main.go
```

В `server/main.go` и `client/main.go` пытаюсь импортировать Network, но все попытки выдают ошибки. Из того, что пробовал:

```go
import (
"GoVersion/network"
"fmt"
"net"
)
```

`package GoVersion/network is not in std`

```go
import (
"fmt"
"net"
"network"
)
```

`package network is not in std`

и несколько других вариантов с относительными путями

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно починить импорты.

Comment: Какое имя модуля у вас в `GoVersion/go/mod`? Пусть к примеру там будет `example.org/some/module`. Тогда импортировать нужно `example.org/some/module/network` - по полному пути.

Comment: Здравствуйте, получилось решить проблему, удалив mod.go, но все равно спасибо за помощь!